# Using JSch to copy one file from remote machine to another remote machine

Tags: java, jsch

I have seen lot of examples of JSch where one can copy from local to remote machine and vice-versa. Is there a way in JSch where I can copy from one remote machine to another remote machine if I am able to provide login credentials for both remote machines.

I have tried following code

```
     JSch jsch=new JSch();
     Session session=jsch.getSession(user1, host1, 22);

     // username and password will be given via UserInfo interface.
     UserInfo ui=new MyUserInfo(password);
     session.setUserInfo(ui);
     session.connect();

     Session remoteSession = jsch.getSession(user2, host2, 22);
     UserInfo ui2 = new MyUserInfo(password2);
     remoteSession.setUserInfo(ui2);
     remoteSession.connect();

     // exec 'scp -f rfile' remotely
     String command="scp -f "+lfile;
     Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
     ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);

     Channel channel2=session.openChannel("exec");
     ((ChannelExec)channel2).setCommand(command);

     // get I/O streams for remote scp
     OutputStream out=channel.getOutputStream();
     InputStream in=channel2.getInputStream();

     channel.connect();
     channel2.connect();
```

which hangs after reading from input stream. Please let me know how could I achieve remote to remote copy.

Answer (score 0):

About the only way I can think of to achieve this is to use JSch to issue the raw SCP command to perform the file transfer from remote host A to remote host B. In order to do this though you'll likely have to set up public key authentication between the two hosts (A and B) so you aren't required to interactively provide a password when connecting to remote host B. Though I do believe it's possible to provide this password via the connection channel, I'm just not sure how.

Comment: Tried that but it is not working :( Any other idea? Gives an error saying that file does not exist.

Comment: Are you seeing that as a Java exception or output on the standard output of remote host A when you invoke SCP? If it's the former I don't think your solution aligns with what I suggested.

Comment: I got it as standard output of remote host